# Nokogiri miss html inner text if it contains "<"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, html-parsing, nokogiri

I am writing a rake task to change HTML string to JSON for which I am using Nokogiri to parse the HTML string and build JSON, everything is going fine until I noticed that if I have an inner text like

```
< 109
```

or

```
> 109
```

then nokogiri returns **"109"**  instead of **"> 109"** or **" < 109"**

if I have a string like

```
str = <td>< 109</td>
```

then

```
result = Nokogiri::XML(str)
```

will return

```
#(Document:0x115f8 {
  name = "document",
  children = [ #(Element:0x1160c { name = "td", children = [ #(Text " 109")] })]
  })
```

and

```
result.children.children.to_s
```

will return **" 109"** but i need **"< 109"**

How can i get desire result?

I am expecting to get **"< 109"** instaed of just **" 109"**

Comment: `<td>< 109</td>` is invalid HTML. The `<` needs to be escaped into the HTML entity `&lt;`. Parsing broken HTML with Nokogiri or any parser is going to be difficult. Where are you getting the bad HTML from?

Comment: Currently, I have a database table that saves an HTML string in a particular column like

`<table class=\"table table-striped\"><tr><th>Zone</th><th>Segment</th><th>Duration</th><th>Power Range (watts)</th><th>HR Range (bpm)</th><th>RPE (1 - 10)</th></tr>
            <tr><td class=\"zone1\">1</td><td>WARM UP</td><td>0:10 at 90-100 RPM</td><td>< 109</td><td>< 121</td><td>1-2</td></tr></table> `

Now, I am writing a rake task to update it to save in json format

Comment: Thats going to very difficult if the data is corrupted like this. If this data is availble from some other source I would try to get it from there.

Comment: Otherwise need to change the focus of you question to how to deal with and fix broken markup with Nokogiri.

Comment: @max is there any workaround to solve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could replace `Nokogiri::XML` with `Nokogiri::HTML`, which is more permissive with incorrect syntax :

```ruby
Nokogiri::XML('<td>< 109</td>').children.last.text  # => " 109"
Nokogiri::HTML('<td>< 109</td>').children.last.text # => "< 109"
```

Answer (score 0):

It's a broken HTML, if this is the only issue that you are trying to solve then you can fix HTML before parsing it. You can replace all `<` with `&lt`.

```rb
str = '<td>< 109</td>'

fixed_str = str.gsub(/>< ([0-9]+)</, '>&lt; \1<')
=> "<td>&lt; 109</td>"

result = Nokogiri::XML(str)
=> #(Document:0x2ac1be2860cc { name = "document", children = [ #(Element:0x2ac1be282940 { name = "td", children = [ #(Text "< 109")] })] })
```

If there are `>` chars too

```rb
fixed_str = str.gsub(/>< ([0-9]+)</, '>&lt; \1<').gsub(/>> ([0-9]+)</, '>&gt; \1<')
```